# Warum “Flugzeug“, nicht “Fliegzeug“?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, history

Flugzeug kommt ja vom Wort “fliegen“, wäre Fliegzeug dann nicht logischer?

Comment: Seit wann ist eine Sprache logisch?

Comment: Interessante Frage, wahrscheinlich unbeantwortbar. Aber wir sollten erstmal ähnliche Wörter untersuchen, um zu sehen, ob Regelmäßigkeiten erkennbar werden. Zunächst fallen mir nur Nähzeug, Flickzeug, Werkzeug  und Zaumzeug ein. Ich befürchte, wir werden nicht genug Wörter mit zwei Vokalen finden, um etwas zu erahnen!

Comment: Es kommt vom Nomen Flug! Trotzdem stellt sich die Frage: „Flieg- oder Flug-?“

Comment: Ich habe schon einmal an der Autobahn ein Schild mit der Aufschrift _Fliegwiese_ gesehen.

Comment: Man sagt umgangssprachlich der Flieger und meint u.a. Das Flugzeug.

Answer (score 20):

> ... wäre Fliegzeug dann nicht logischer?

Definitiv nein:

Ich bin gerade einige Verben durchgegangen, bei denen sich das Substantiv, das die Tätigkeit beschreibt, und das Verb im Vokal unterscheiden:

- spr**i**ngen - der Spr**u**ng
- s**i**ngen - der Ges**a**ng (*)
- w**ä**hlen - die W**a**hl
- k**ä**mpfen - der K**a**mpf
- fl**ie**gen - der Fl**u**g

(*) zugegeben, passt nicht ganz

Danach habe ich mir einige zusammengesetzte Substantive angeschaut, die etwas bezeichnen, was man zum Ausführen der entsprechenden Tätigkeit benötigt.

Meistens wird das Wort nicht vom Verb, sondern vom Substantiv, das die Tätigkeit beschreibt, abgeleitet:

- Sprungschanze - und nicht Springschanze
- Gesangspartitur - und nicht Singpartitur
- Wahlunterlagen - und nicht Wählunterlagen
- Kampfmesser - und nicht Kämpfmesser
- Flugzeug - und nicht Fliegzeug

Eine Ausnahme, die ich auf die Schnelle gefunden habe:

Das Wort "*Gehstock*" ist mir zumindest geläufiger als "*Gangstock*", obwohl laut Internet beide Varianten existieren.

Comment: Sehr gute Antwort.

Comment: Aber Springform, Springteufel, Singstimme.

Comment: Springteufel => der Teufel springt; Sprungschanze => jemand anders springt, nicht die Schanze. Singstimme => die Stimme mit der gesungen wird; Gesangspartitur => es ist nicht die Partitur die singt, sondern ein Hilfsmittel zum Singen. Ich denke das zeigt ziemlich gut, dass sich in der Regel der Vokal ändert, wenn das Nomen ein Hilfsmittel zur Tätigkeit des Verbs ist. Wenn das Verb das Nomen spezifiziert dann bleibt der Vokal erhalten.

Comment: Das Flugzeug wird also als Hilfsmittel zum Fliegen betrachtet. Das kommt wohl hauptsächlich daher das "-zeug" generell ein Hilfsmittel für eine Tätigkeit beschreibt

Comment: Es heißt ja auch das Feuerzeug und nicht Anzündzeug oder Zündzeug. Obwohl es in Österreich zum Beispiel gern global (inkl. Streichhölzer) als Zünder genannt wird.

Answer (score -4):

- "fliegen" = "to fly"
- "Flug" = "flight"

Thus,

- "Flugzeug" = "flight device", i.e. a device for flight.

Comment: Es scheint so, das ist nicht meine beste Antwort.

Comment: Der Ansatz ist interessant, aber eine Sprache ist nunmal durch eine Kultur geprägt, daher macht es wenig Sinn sie über eine andere Sprache zu erklären.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Richtig. Aber ich sehe es nicht so großem Problem zu sein. Auch englisch ist erlaubt hier.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. "'Fliegzeug' = 'flying-device', i.e. a device for flying" would be just as logical an explanation.